# How to approach problem of creating graphic buttons with dynamic text for web page

Tags: css, xhtml, button

I want to be able to create links looking like buttons with dynamic text and graphic bakground, these buttons also have to change their apperance on mouse over/mouse down and when subpage which button corresponding to is currently opened ame as mouse down)

I want to avoid using 
 - java script/jquery
 - server-side generated images
 - flash

Ny first choice was CSS, technology called sliding-doors. Everyting was great until i tested my site on non-windows machine. And it seems that there is poblem with rendering same font of different platforms. I suspect that problem is connected with way of rendering of fonts of different systems or maybe somethuiing elese, anyway on MAC (and possibly on machines running linux) it looks like this

http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/3598/45257410.png

on windows it looks slightly different and in some way worse

http://img168.imageshack.us/img168/3590/41024479.png

If it is possible to get the same effect?

What other choices do i have?

I considered using CSS sprites, and manipulating button-link size and background position only but this including creating a wide image with all buttons in certain language with all three states.Is that way would be efficent? Is there any serious directions to not use this way of creating buttons?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions
MTH

Comment: Not much you can do if a system's font's don't look as good.  The only thing you really can do is go with a large sprite like you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fonts are machine dependent.  Outside of the basic ones, you cannot depend on a machine having the font you want.  You need to have 3-4 roughly equivalent fonts, that you list for any given font in your css.  List them most prefered to least (left to right) for your font-family.  Machines will also display even some common fonts slightly differently.

Also remember that while you will often pull your site up side by side in both IE and Firefox, on Mac and Linux, your users almost never will.  It doesn't need to look the *same* in all browsers, it just needs to look good in all browsers.

You're basically asking for rich functionality without any of the rich functionality platforms (javascript, flash, etc.)

I realize this doesn't answer your question, I'm trying to step it back a bit.  Image rollover without any of the above platforms is hard, but possible.  But it will probably require that you give up on the site being exactly the same in all browsers and just go for "good"

Comment: I'm aware of system diffrences but i hoped that it is possible to jump over it some way still using text and sliding doors tehnology

Comment: There are two separate questions here.  "Can I create a button toggle effect with sliding doors?"  and "Can I make fonts look uniform across all browsers?"  The answer to the first is yes, and the answer to the second is no.  So the answer to "Can I do both together" is unforunately "no".